# Paypal with Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, paypal

Do you guys know how to implement paypal with laravel 5.3? I have looked for some information but I'm not sure about it. If you know about any tutorial please let me know.
Thanks!

Comment: This isn't enough information since there are many packages to help facilitate working with the PayPal API.  Different packages may benefit you more or less based on the logic required from your website/app.  I suggest looking through some github packages and asking a question more specifically about the one you've selected. https://www.google.ca/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=paypal%20laravel%20github.  Additionally, if you are simply looking for a payment proccessor and aren't tied to Paypal, I'd look at Stripe.  https://laracasts.com/series/billing-with-stripe

Comment: Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For my personal experience I've used the paypal php SDK [link here](http://paypal.github.io/PayPal-PHP-SDK/)

I've also constructed a helper containing the integration which I will share here. It's a complete flow and there are steps which i would advise to read about.

```
class PaypalHelper {

  private $apiContext;
  protected $payer;
  protected $transaction;
  protected $payment;
  protected $redirectUrls;

  /**
   * Instantiate a new helper instance.
   *
   * @return void
   */
  public function __construct() {
    $this->payer = new Payer();
    $this->transaction = new Transaction();
    $this->redirectUrls = new RedirectUrls();
    $this->payment = new Payment();
    $this->redirectUrls = new RedirectUrls();

    $this->apiContext = new \PayPal\Rest\ApiContext(
      new \PayPal\Auth\OAuthTokenCredential(
        config('paypal')['client_id'],
        config('paypal')['secret']
        )
    );

    $this->apiContext->setConfig(
      config('paypal')['settings']
    );
  }

  /**
   * Get api context.
   *
   * @return void
   */
  public function getApiContext() {
    return $this->apiContext;
  }

  /**
   * Set payment method.
   *
   * @return void
   */
  public function setPaymentMethod($method) {
    $this->payer->setPaymentMethod($method);
  }

  /**
   * Set funding instrument.
   *
   * @return void
   */
  public function setFundingInstrument($fi) {
    $this->payer->setFundingInstruments([$fi]);
  }

  /**
   * Set redirect urls.
   *
   * @return void
   */
  public function setRedirectUrls($return_url, $cancel_url) {
    $this->redirectUrls
      ->setReturnUrl($return_url)
      ->setCancelUrl($cancel_url);
  }

  /**
   * Build product list.
   *
   * @return void
   */
  public function buildProductList($products) {
    $productList = new ItemList();

    $products->each(function($product, $key) use ($productList) {
      $item = new Item();
      $description = '';

      $product->attributes->each(function($attribute, $key) use (&$description) {
        if(!is_object($attribute)) {
          if($key !== 0) {
            $description = $description . ' | ' . $attribute;
          } else {
            $description = $attribute;
          }
        }
      });

      $item->setName($product->name)
        ->setDescription($description)
        ->setCurrency('EUR')
        ->setQuantity($product->quantity)
        ->setSku($product->reference)
        ->setPrice($product->price);

      $productList->addItem($item);
    });

    return $productList;
  }

  /**
   * Calculate details
   *
   * @return Response
   */
  public function calculateDetails($totals) {
    $details = new Details();

    $details->setShipping(0)
      ->setTax(0)
      ->setSubtotal($totals['total']);

    return $details;
  }

  /**
   * Calculate total amount
   *
   * @return Response
   */
  public function calculateTotalAmount($totals, $details) {
    $amount = new Amount();

    $total = $details->getTax() + $details->getShipping() + $totals['total'];

    $amount->setCurrency('EUR')
      ->setTotal($total)
      ->setDetails($details);

    return $amount;
  }

  /**
   * Build transaction.
   *
   * @return void
   */
  public function buildTransaction($amount, $productList) {
    $this->transaction
      ->setAmount($amount)
      ->setItemList($productList)
      ->setDescription('')
      ->setInvoiceNumber(uniqid());

    return $this->transaction;
  }

  /**
   * Build payment.
   *
   * @return void
   */
  public function buildPayment() {
    $this->payment
      ->setIntent('sale')
      ->setPayer($this->payer)
      ->setRedirectUrls($this->redirectUrls)
      ->setTransactions([$this->transaction]);

    return $this->payment;
  }
}
```

I would look at the examples they have in their documentation. If you wanna look at the project you can check it out [here](https://github.com/pedromrb/papelariaalcaide). Hope this helps.